# How do you stop wobbling in a carbon nano tube elevator to space?

Tags: experimental-physics

If there was a carbon nanotube elevator that went to space how would you keep it from wobbling?

As I picture it I see the structure being very strong, but would that prevent wobbling? It would be like a tall, thin building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post-1959 proposals for such a structure are meant to be under tension: the centrifugal force of Earth rotation balances its weight. Thus it is tensed as a rope that you would swing in circles. The tension in the structure is acting against wobbling.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the tension, you need some sort of damping of transverse vibrations.  There might be enough in the elevator structure-once a design is made that can be assessed.  It might help to put some rubber around the joints.  You might put active control-motors that can tighten/loosen specific strands at the right frequency to damp vibration.

It is a real problem, but one that cannot be solved until you understand the properties of the design.  NASA has done a lot of research into flexible structures and control.  This is one example.

Comment: See _tuned mass damper_.